# Vert.x MongoClient error "Command failed with error 9: 'The 'cursor' option is required, except for aggregate..."

Tags: java, mongodb, vert.x

- Vert.x Version : 3.4.1
- MongoDB server version: 4.0.2

While running aggregate query, I am getting below error:

> Command failed with error 9: 'The 'cursor' option is required, except for aggregate with the explain argument' on server localhost:27017. The full response is { "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "The 'cursor' option is required, except for aggregate with the explain argument", "code" : 9, "codeName" : "FailedToParse" }

**Sample code is as below:**

```
JsonObject command = new JsonObject().put("aggregate", "someCollection").put("pipeline", jsonArray);
    client.runCommand("aggregate", command, res -> {
        if (res.succeeded()) {
            JsonArray resArr = res.result().getJsonArray("result");
            future.complete(resArr);
            } else {
                future.fail(res.cause());
                }
        });
```

What should I do to resolve this issue in vert.x MongoClient?

Answer (score 0):

That error doesn't seems to be related to the vert.x client but to your query. I'm not really familiar with MongoDB but I think you need to add a `cursor` attribute in your `JsonObject` according to the error message from MongoDB.

[This](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) and [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#example-aggregate-method-initial-batch-size) might help you to initialize the cursor attribute of your query.

You might should test the JSON directly on a mongodb cli to reproduce this error and fix your query before the implementation.

Comment: This code is working fine on mongo 3.4 and below but not working on mongo 3.6 and above.
Is there any way apart from using cursor in aggregate option.

Comment: @PrashantGupta It seems to became required in the 3.6 version. Why don't you try to add a cursor with a batchSize ?

Comment: It seems, in vert.x, cursor with batched will not solved the problem as we do not have provision to fetch next batch.
References: https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-mongo-client/issues/148

Comment: @PrashantGupta I think you should look at the workaround proposed by HendrikLanghammer in your issue link.